# Does an entire Object Graph get collected by the .net Garbage Collector?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

Lets say ObjectA has sole reference to ObjectB and ObjectB has sole reference to ObjectC. If ObjectA no longer has any references to it, when ObjectA gets garbage collected, will ObjectB and ObjectC get garbage collected too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how accurate you want an answer to be.

First of all, when an object no longer has any rooted references referring to it, the object is said to be "eligible for collection".

A "rooted reference" is a reference via any path that originates from a "root" that ends up referring to the object. One such type of root are all static fields in the appdomain, another would be local variables on methods still on the callstack, provided those methods still have a use for this reference.

So let's take your example.

Object A refers to B, B refers to C. No other references are considered.

The reference from A to B is removed, leaving B without a rooted reference. C, as well, have no rooted reference, since there is no way to go from a root to C via other objects.

As such, when you remove the reference to B from A, both B and C are now *eligible for collection*.

However, they're not necessarily collected immediately, nor do they have to be collected as part of the same collection cycle.

Very simplified, the .NET memory management system is built around 3 different heaps, generation 0 through generation 2. There is also a "large object heap" but this is not really necessary for this answer. Generation 0 is where all objects are initially constructed, and when this fills up, a garbage collection cycle of generation 0 is performed, analyzing which objects are still rooted, and which aren't.

All the objects that are rooted survive and become part of generation 1 (the next generation), all objects that no longer had any rooted references were collected. Objects with finalizers doesn't follow this rule, but again this isn't really relevant here.

When generation 1 fills up, it too is collected, moving surviving objects into generation 2.

Generation 0, 1 and 2, are not necessarily collected at the same time. You can have multiple collections of generation 0 before a collection of generation 1 becomes necessary.

So, if B and C are part of different generations, then no, they won't necessarily be collected at the same time.

They **did**, however, become **eligible for collection** at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Don't think about the garbage collector as looking for objects that don't have any references. Think of it as keeping objects alive that *do* have references.

Basically: when you allocate a new object, where does the memory come from? Anywhere in memory that doesn't have an object that is still alive (that is, that could still be used somehow by running code). Any part of memory that no running code can reach anymore is unreachable, and the GC will use unreachable memory space for new objects to be allocated into.

(Modern GCs also move objects around in memory to make it easier to allocate new ones, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.)

Answer (score 1):

For example :

```
class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "...";
    public object Ref { get; set; }

    ~Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} is finalized.");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var objectA = new Foo
        {
            Name = "Object A",
            Ref = new Foo
            {
                Name = "Object B",
                Ref = new Foo
                {
                    Name = "Object C"
                }
            }
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Begin");
        objectA = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Ouput :

```
Begin
Object C is finalized.
Object B is finalized.
Object A is finalized.
End
```

Other fact it's loop of reference. If Object A reference Object B reference Object C reference Object A :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var objectA = new Foo
        {
            Name = "Object A",
            Ref = new Foo
            {
                Name = "Object B",
                Ref = new Foo
                {
                    Name = "Object C"
                }
            }
        };
        ((Foo)((Foo) objectA.Ref).Ref).Ref = objectA;
        Console.WriteLine("Begin");
        Console.WriteLine(objectA.Name);
        objectA = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("End");
    }
}
```

Ouput :

```
Begin
Object C is finalized.
Object B is finalized.
Object A is finalized.
End
```

You need understand the start of graph object is App Domain. In the last example :

```
App Domain -> Object A -> Object B -> Object C -|
               ↑----------------------------|
```